# BAD_Access while using RDP(Static library) with Opnetok in iOS?

Tags: ios, rdp, opentok

RDP static library works fine if I comment out the code written for OPentok, if I  try to work both together it gives BAD_Access Error at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that there are incompatibilities between the SSL library versions used in each. OpenTok uses boringssl, which happens to export symbol names that are identical to those in openssl.

Comment: its bad access when  its comes to RAND_Bytes method, and if comment the code(using opentok) it works very fine